# Assign data to a group in a random order, respecting constraints in Excel

Tags: excel

I have about a thousand rows of data that I would like to assign to random groups that follow some rules. I have tried a lot of ways with no success, and I have not found any answers online so I'm hoping you can help.

Basically, I have rows of data sort of like this:

```
Key   Description   Weight    Group
1     Orange        0.987
2     Apple         0.876
3     Melon         0.765
4     Peach         0.654
5     Mango         0.432
6     Banana        0.321
7     Kiwi          0.219
```

And so on, always sorted from highest to lowest weight...
Now, I want to divide into groups that follow two set of rules: exact amount of Keys in each group and an approximate sum of the weight. So, let's say there are 2 groups for this example that must follow the rules:

```
Group     # of keys    Sum of weight
1         4            2.8
2         3            1.6
```

So, an example output would be:

```
Key   Description   Weight    Group
1     Orange        0.987     1
2     Apple         0.876     2
3     Melon         0.765     1
4     Peach         0.654     2
5     Mango         0.432     1
6     Banana        0.321     1
7     Kiwi          0.219     2
```

So here there are 4 fruits in group 1 with a resulting weight of 2.51, and 3 fruits in group 2 with weight of 1.75.

The goal here is to match the # of keys in a group exactly to what's expected and that the sum of the weight is similar to what's expected (maybe with a surplus of up to 10%). PLUS, the groups shouldn't follow any apparent order (the top keys always for group 1, for example), but instead be as random as possible.

I have tried with formulas and so far I've come up with ways to match the # of keys for each group, but the weights are VERY different from what's expected. I would prefer that it is resolved with formulas, but if VBA is needed it's no problem.

> Tl;dr: I'm looking to assign groups to a set of rows making sure that
>   the number of rows for each group is constrained by user inputs, and
>   that the sum of a column for each group is similar to a given
>   "goal"(defined by user) for each group. Preferably without VBA.

Comment: So for group #2 any triplet with sum_of_weights between 1.6-10% and 1.6+10%.............that is between 1.44 and 1.76 ??

Comment: That's right, so long it is close to the given number, it would be an acceptable arrangement of the groups